# Send data to user through proxy JS/PHP

Tags: javascript, proxy, download

I have a proxy (IP + Port) and I have some data on a different server (not mine).
The only way to get this data is through proxy (static IP).

The problem is, I don't want the data to go through my server to.
I want it to get from the remote server to the user through the proxy.

But, I don't want the user to change anything in their browser settings, I want it to be auotomatic.

Thanks!